# How to check nil for Swift Optionals with out unwrap it?

Tags: swift

I knew that safely unwrapping is as follows

```
var firstName:String?

if let firstName = firstName
{
    dictionary.setObject(firstName, forKey: "firstName")
}
else 
{
    dictionary.setObject("", forKey: "firstName")
}
```

I want to add firstname to dictionary even it is nil also. I will have 10-15 var's in dictionary. 
I do not want to check for this condition 10-15 times for ear var.
I am having more than 1000 optionals through out project.

So thought of writing  writing a func will help me duplicate the code and reduce the number of lines.
So implemented this func as below.

```
func checkNull(str:String) -> String
{
    return str.characters.count > 0 ? "\(str)" : ""
}
```

but while calling the func,

```
let addressstr = self.checkNull(address?.firstName)
```

firstname is the var in address model here.
The auto correction sugguests

```
let addressstr = self.checkNull((address?.firstName)!)
```

The above line causes the crash.

Comment: Don't use count. If you have a string of a million characters it counts the million characters. Use isEmpty. (That is after fixing the other things)

Comment: when ever a character added to string then automatically count will increase. Even if it is million also no matter it wont count when we call the method. It just return the value stored in count object. Coming to your question, always create a string with "" value.
Then look for if string != "" then there is a value or return the "" so you can handle accordingly with out checking for optional and unwrap etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all `firstName` is an `Optional` therefore you cannot pass it to a function which only takes `String`.

In addition this line:

```
str.characters.count > 0 ? "\(str)" : ""
```

Is equivalent to just returning `str` so you don't check whether it is an `Optional`.

### Solution

In this case it is way easier to use the [nil coalescing operator](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/BasicOperators.html):

```
let addressstr = address?.firstName ?? ""
```

If `address` is not nil `firstName` gets unwrapped and bind to `addressstr`. Otherwise this string gets assigned to it: `""`